# Grails - How to unregister an already registered object marshaller

Tags: json, grails, groovy, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a domain class `Person` in my grails application that I need to output in different forms (of JSON) depending on the context.

In one context, I need to render only a couple of fields (say id and name). In another context, I want to render a lot more (id, name, credentials, age etc..). I'm wondering if it is possible to unregister a particular marshaller right after use.

Essentially what I'm looking for is something like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------

// context #1
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Person) {
    ... output just id and name
}

render myPerson as JSON

JSON.unregisterObjectMarshaller(Person) // how do i do this?

-------------------------------------------------------------

// context #2
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Person) {
    ... output all fields
}

render myPerson as JSON

JSON.unregisterObjectMarshaller(Person) // how do i do this?

-------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Note:** I can create 2 empty subclasses for Person and then have separate Marshallers registered for each. As the number of *contexts* increase the number of dummy subclasses will also go up. This is very unclean imo.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'd probably want to use what's called a named config instead of 'swapping' marshallers. You can wrap this up into a neater class/utility, but somewhere (like Bootstrap.groovy), do:

```
JSON.createNamedConfig('thin') {
    it.registerObjectMarshaller( Person ) { Person person ->
        return [
            id: person.id,
            name: person.name,
        ]
    }
}

JSON.createNamedConfig('full') {
    it.registerObjectMarshaller( Person ) { Person person ->
        return [
                id: person.id,
                name: person.name,
                age: person.age
        ]
    }
}
```

Then, in a controller, you can choose which style of marshalled person to show:

```
// Show lots of stuff
JSON.use('full') {
    render people as JSON
}
```

or

```
// Show less stuff
JSON.use('thin') {
    render people as JSON
}
```

Comment: +1 This is beautiful. And very clean. Thank you. I'll put it in and let you know how it went.

Comment: This is a great solution. Is there a way to use this with Grails' 'respond' feature, so using named marshallers for XML and JSON?

Comment: And speaking of bundling it up nicely, here's one approach to doing that: http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/